# Получить order_id в редактируемой таблице

Tags: php, javascript

Есть таблица в ней поле ttn нужно что бы оно редактировалось, при клике появляется поле для изменения данных.

view

```
 <td><?php echo $order['order_id'];?></td>           
 <td class="edit"><?php echo $order['ttn']?></td>



$('.edit').on('click', function () {
      $(this).html("<input type='text' name='ttn' value='" + $(this).text() + "'/>");

  }).on('click', 'input', function () {
      return false;
  }).on('blur', 'input', function () {
      $(this).parent('td').text($(this).val());

      var ttn = $(this).val();

      console.log(ttn);

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'index.php?route=account/order',
          data:{"ttn":ttn},
          success: function (data) {
             // получаю отредактированные данные
          }
      });
  });
```

а как получить order_id, отредактированного поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В td.edit добавляем data-order:

```
<td><?php echo $order['order_id'];?></td>
<td class="edit" data-order="<?php echo $order['order_id'];?>">
    <?php echo $order['ttn']?>
</td>
```

В js получаем его (После var tnn):

```
$('.edit').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html("<input type='text' name='ttn' value='" + $(this).text() + "'/>");

}).on('click', 'input', function () {
    return false;
}).on('blur', 'input', function () {
    $(this).parent('td').text($(this).val());

    var ttn = $(this).val();
    var order_id = $(this).parent('td').data('order'); // Здесь твой ордер
    // var order_id = $(this).parent('td').prev('td').text(); // без data-order, но менее надежно, т.к. если изменить порядок td тегов, то prev('td') вернет другое значение.

    console.log(ttn);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?route=account/order',
        data:{"ttn":ttn},
        success: function (data) {
           // получаю отредактированные данные
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное !

Answer (score 1):

> а как получить order_id, отредактированного поля.

при загрузке html

```
.....
<td><?php echo $order['order_id'];?></td>        
.....
```

отдать этот атрибут строке

```
<tr order_id ="<?=$order['order_id'];?>" >
...<td></td>..<td></td>...
</tr>
```

а затем получать у строки этот атрибут, который можно использовать во многих операциях удаления, редактирования и прочее.

т.е.

```
 var ttn = $(this).parent().attr('order_id');
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'index.php?route=account/order',
          data:{"ttn":ttn},
          success: function (data) {
             // получаю отредактированные данные
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Толком вопроса не понял (новичок я), но если проблема в "после загрузки", то вот тема...

```
window.addEventListener("load", test, false);

function test() {
    alert('test');
}
```

Таким образом загрузятся все динамо данные и можно парсить дальше.

И главное завязывай с Jquery.